# Get the data from REST and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest

I am learning HTML and javascript. I am stuck at one place. My requirement is to make a call to REST API and get the value and then redirect the page to another URL.

Code Snippet:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    //REST SERVICE CALL
    <form action="http://localhost:51349/SMS_Rest.svc/v1/CheckBox"  method="get" > 
        <input type="checkbox" id = "1" name="graphId" value="1"> Graph1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id = "2" name="graphId" value="2"> Graph2<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id = "3" name="graphId" value="3"> Graph3<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id = "4" name="graphId" value="4"> Graph4<br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I hit Submit I get the response from REST Service as TRUE. But the URL I get redirected to automatically matches with the REST URL mentioned in the action field of HTML. But I want to fetch data from REST and then redirect user to another page. Am I making sense here. Kindly help me.

Comment: I think you watch to fetch the data via ajax, and when done, redirect with javascript. Not submit the form to your API. Read about jquery AJAX calls.http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I can think of would be to submit the form with AJAX then redirect to the URL that you want to:

First you'll need jQuery Form plugin -  [Ajax Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)
Then after adding id="rest-form" to your form:

```
jQuery("#rest-form").submit(function(e){
    //The following stops the form from redirecting
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#rest-form").ajaxSubmit({
        type: 'GET',
        url: jQuery('#rest-form').attr('action'),
        data: jQuery('#rest-form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            //The data variable will contain the response data
            //if it's successful, you can no redirect wherever you want
            window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the submit who trigger the redirect.
I suggest you to use an AJAX call, something like this :

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:51349/SMS_Rest.svc/v1/CheckBox?graphId=" + graphId, true);
xhttp.send();
var response = xhttp.responseText;
```

Get the response of the request, and if correct redirect like this :

```
document.location.href="redirectionTarget";
```

EDIT : Native javascript is a bit crappy, you may want to use library like jquery instead, as mentionned by Leeish.

Answer (score 1):

From what you used in your question you are using a form to make a REST call? This is not the usual way to make REST call. But if you insist on doing this, you need to change the response of your REST service to respond with a redirect such as :

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/otherpage
```

The other way do to this would be to post your form on a non REST endpoint which would do your form validation for example. If you need to call your REST service before to do some other client side validation you should use `window.XMLHttpRequest` to process the REST call asynchronously before you submit the form (`onsubmit` event). There are more details here on how to achive this: http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-javascript.html

But maybe you just need to post your form normally, depending on your use case. But submitting a form to a REST service is probably not the standard approach you want to use.

Comment: You are totally correct. Since I learning so I did not have all this idea. I should change my code.